# ArcGIS hillshade creates artifact on tile boundary

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, hillshade

I'm working with ArcGIS on a DTM made of 1x1km tiles (cell size 20cm). When I try to create an hillshade model based on this DTM I get visual artifacts on tile junctions, whereas there are no visible drop or gap on the DTM itself.

[image: Edge artifact between tiles]

*Edge artifact between tiles*

[image: DTM Cross section] [image]

*DTM Cross section*

I get the same result if I combine first the tiles and create the hillshade model or if I create the hillshade model tile by tile.
I also get the same result if I create the hillshade model with Global Mapper.

Do you have any advice to overcome this issue ?

Comment: I tend to have better luck working with with raster tiles in a "Mosaic Dataset" in a file geodatabse.  Perhaps creating your hillshade from a mosaic dataset rather than from multiple individual tiles will eliminate the edge effects?
 http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/what-is-a-mosaic-dataset.htm

Comment: During mosaic to a new raster choose blend option.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried both solutions but still get the same result. The question stays open

Comment: Looking at your first image the surface appears to be made up of triangles, is your raster derived from a TIN?

Comment: Yes, my raster is derived from a TIN. The TIN was created with a LiDAR point cloud